# Hive Query returns cartesian product instead of inner join

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

This is type of query I am sending to HIVE:

```
SELECT BigTable.nicefield,LargeTable.* 
FROM LargeTable INNER JOIN BigTable 
    ON (
        LargeTable.joinfield1of4 = BigTable.joinfield1of4 
        AND LargeTable.joinfield2of4 = BigTable.joinfield2of4 
    )   
WHERE LargeTable.joinfield3of4=20140726 AND LargeTable.joinfield4of4=15 AND BigTable.joinfield3of4=20140726 AND BigTable.joinfield4of4=15
    AND LargeTable.filterfiled1of2=123456
    AND LargeTable.filterfiled2of2=98765
    AND LargeTable.joinfield2of4=12 
    AND LargeTable.joinfield1of4='iwanttolikehive'
```

It returns `2418025` rows.  The issue is that

```
SELECT *  
FROM LargeTable 
WHERE joinfield3of4=20140726 AND joinfield4of4=15
    AND filterfiled1of2=123456 
    AND filterfiled2of2=98765
    AND joinfield2of4=12 
    AND joinfield1of4='iwanttolikehive'
```

returns `1555` rows, and so does:

```
SELECT *  
FROM BigTable 
WHERE joinfield3of4=20140726 AND joinfield4of4=15
    AND joinfield2of4=12 
    AND joinfield1of4='iwanttolikehive'
```

Note that **1555^2 = 2418025**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the correct version of the query should be:

```
SELECT bt.nicefield,LargeTable.* 
FROM LargeTable INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT nicefield, joinfield1of4,joinfield2of4, count(*) as rows
    FROM BigTable
    WHERE joinfield3of4=20140726 ANDjoinfield4of4=15
    GROUP BY nicefield, joinfield1of4,joinfield2of4
    ) bt 
    ON (
        LargeTable.joinfield1of4 = bt.joinfield1of4 
        AND LargeTable.joinfield2of4 = bt.joinfield2of4 
    )   
WHERE LargeTable.joinfield3of4=20140726 AND LargeTable.joinfield4of4=15
    AND LargeTable.filterfiled1of2=123456
    AND LargeTable.filterfiled2of2=98765
    AND LargeTable.joinfield2of4=12 
    AND LargeTable.joinfield1of4='iwanttolikehive'
```

The issue is that in the original query, the join on the `BigTable` was returning duplicates.

**This is NOT an issue**, queries just have to be written carefully!!!
I hope this help!